# Cant display Web API response on a WPF form

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a project I have been working on using the RiotGames API, and for some reason I cannot get the API response to display on my WPF form, I make two requests to 2 different API's and only one of them is displaying on the form. I'm not sure exactly what's happening, but any feedback would be nice, doesn't need to be a full solution.

Here is my MainWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        initalProfileLoad();
        initalRankedLoad();
    }

    private async Task initalProfileLoad()
    {
        await APIConnect.getSummonerByName(Regions.NA, summoner, "Fusion Icee");
        this.tbSummonerName.Text = summoner.name;
        this.tbSummonerLevel.Text = summoner.summonerLevel.ToString();
    }

    private async Task initalRankedLoad()
    {
        var rHandler = new RankHandler();
        var rankedSummoner = new LSummonerRanked();

        await APIConnect.getSummonerRankBySummonerID(Regions.NA, rankedSummoner, summoner.id);
        this.tbRankDivision.Text = rankedSummoner.tier + "" + rankedSummoner.rank;
        this.imgRankedIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(rHandler.getRankedIcon(rankedSummoner.tier).ToString()));
    }
```

I put the two connections into separate methods for loading purposes in case i was maxing out requests..

Here is my APIConnect.cs file:

```
public static async Task getSummonerByName(Regions _rg, LSummoner summoner, string summonerName)
    {
        var summ = new LSummoner();

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Region region = new Region();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://" + region.getRegionConnectionString(_rg));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"{SUMMONER_API}{summonerName}?api_key={API_KEY}");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                LSummoner lSummoner = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<LSummoner>();
                summoner.name = lSummoner.name; summoner.profileIconId = lSummoner.profileIconId;
                summoner.puuid = lSummoner.puuid; summoner.summonerLevel = lSummoner.summonerLevel;
                summoner.revisionDate = lSummoner.revisionDate; summoner.id = lSummoner.id;
                summoner.accountId = lSummoner.accountId;
            }
            else
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the summoner by an Encrypted Summoner ID from the RiotGames API
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_rg"></param>
    /// <param name="summoner"></param>
    /// <param name="encryptedSummonerID"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static async Task getSummonerByid(Regions _rg, string encryptedSummonerID)
    {
        var summ = new LSummoner();

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Region region = new Region();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://" + region.getRegionConnectionString(_rg));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-account/{encryptedSummonerID}?api_key={API_KEY}");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                LSummoner lSummoner = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<LSummoner>();
                summ.summoners.Add(new LSummoner(lSummoner.profileIconId, lSummoner.name, lSummoner.puuid, lSummoner.summonerLevel, lSummoner.revisionDate,
                    lSummoner.id, lSummoner.accountId));
            }
            else
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the ranked data of a summoner by the Encrypted SummonerID from the RiotGames API
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_rg"></param>
    /// <param name="summoner"></param>
    /// <param name="encryptedSummonerID"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task getSummonerRankBySummonerID(Regions _rg, LSummonerRanked summonerRanked, string encryptedSummonerID)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Region region = new Region();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://" + region.getRegionConnectionString(_rg));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"{RANKED_API}{encryptedSummonerID}?api_key={API_KEY}");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                LSummonerRanked lSummonerRanked = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<LSummonerRanked>();
                summonerRanked.summonerName = lSummonerRanked.summonerName; summonerRanked.tier = lSummonerRanked.tier;
                summonerRanked.rank = lSummonerRanked.rank;
            }
            else
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }
    }
```

Both the LSummoner and LSummonerRanked objects have {get; set;} accessors for the public data types.
Any help would be nice, not expecting a solution, just a point in the right direction. I would like to try and learn from these mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: The question is not clear and it's hard to give you any specific response. Please narrow it and add detailed description of the problem and error message if present.

Comment: By the way - I noticed that you are using HttpClient in a wrong way, for details read this https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: There isnt an error message, so basically what happens when I run the program, the first GET request to the server goes through and displays the result on the WPF application. But when the second GET request goes out (getSummonerRankBySummonerID()), nothing happens. It doesnt throw a web excpetion or anything. The task just never completes. But when I go to the web api webpage and query a request against it with the same summonerID, I get a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the nature of the calls being made which is mixing UI and worker threads, It would be better to use an async event handler

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    //On UI thread here...

    //On worker thread here (non-blocking)
    await APIConnect.getSummonerByName(Regions.NA, summoner, "Fusion Icee");

    //Back on UI Thread
    this.tbSummonerName.Text = summoner.name;
    this.tbSummonerLevel.Text = summoner.summonerLevel.ToString();

    var rHandler = new RankHandler();
    var rankedSummoner = new LSummonerRanked();

    //On worker thread (non-blocking)
    await APIConnect.getSummonerRankBySummonerID(Regions.NA, rankedSummoner, summoner.id);

    //Back on UI thread
    this.tbRankDivision.Text = rankedSummoner.tier + "" + rankedSummoner.rank;
    this.imgRankedIcon.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(rHandler.getRankedIcon(rankedSummoner.tier).ToString()));
}
```

Review the comments to understand the flow

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Could you evaluate what i did wrong before?